# How to allow a web-app to use jetty server classes?

Tags: jetty

I am using jetty 9. 
I need to use in my web app a class that is in jetty server libs e.g. org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler. When jetty is started it includes its libs in classpath. But when I try to use it from my web app I get class not found exception. I guess WEB-INF/lib classes and jetty server classes are loaded by different class loaders. So I added in etc/jetty-deploy.xml  to WebAppProvider

```
<Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
```

hoping that webapp classloader would delegate classloading to its parent. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I am using jetty 8. I set the parameter in webapp jetty-web.xml:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  ...
  <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
  ...
</Configure>
```

The parameter itself however is not enough because `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader` avoids "system" and "server" classes, see [jetty classloading doc](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html). Thus, in order to allow e.g. server classes from `org.eclipse.jetty.util` you need to tell your webapp about it, e.g. by

```
  <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
  <Call name="addServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclise.jetty.util</Arg>
  </Call>
```

(the '-' before package name means "remove" instead of add)

Answer (score 1):

I'll describe here what worked for me. This can change in future versions of Jetty, so please make sure the version you use is compatible with these configurations.

My Jetty version: 9.4.5.v20170502.

**Step 1: don't change any Jetty internal files**

When trying to make the things work we sometimes change the internal configuration of the server hoping it would make a difference. While I think this configuration can be set at the server level, I strongly discourage it, simply because it makes your application not portable across different Jetty servers.

**Step 2: move all Jetty-related JARs you need to your classpath**

That means copying `jetty-server-<version>.jar`, `jetty-servlets-<version>.jar` and any other `jetty-<something>-<version>.jar` you need to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

If you use Maven, just declare those dependencies in your `pom.xml` without specifying any scope.

There are other ways to include those files in your classpath, but again, I discourage changing any server files due to portability reasons.

**Step 3: create a jetty-web.xml file**

This file contains settings specific to Jetty. It is located at `WEB-INF`, in the same place where the `web.xml` file is located.

Then, inside this `jetty-web.xml`, use the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
  <Call name="addServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.server.</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="addServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.http.</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

(Use the packages of the classes you want to import. You can add as many classes or packages you want by repeating the `Call` structure).

Please note the `-` sign in front of the name of the packages - this means that the server should remove that package from the forbidden list. And also note the `.` in the end of the package name.

More information about the classloading process in Jetty: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.5.v20170502/jetty-classloading.html